# Need help in displaying my jquery dynamic field and auto complete calculations in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am currently working on dynamic field using jquery that will will do calcalution of items and display their total result immediately once all the inputs parameters are filled.

The things is the code total calculations, add new field and remove btn stop working when I use it with @extendlayout('') but works when i dont. Also i Think it is important I note that when i place the code into my target form and click the create new field or remove buton, it was trying to submit the form, instead of creating and removing the new field.

The aim is to include it inside the form i am currently working on and send the input and total results to my database but I need it to work first to accomplish that.

```js
$(function() {

  function autoCalcSetup() {
    $('div#cart').jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $('div#cart tr.line_items').jAutoCalc({
      keyEventsFire: true,
      decimalPlaces: 2,
      emptyAsZero: true
    });
    $('div#cart').jAutoCalc({
      decimalPlaces: 2
    });
  }
  autoCalcSetup();


  $('button.row-remove').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).parents('div')
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    autoCalcSetup();

  });

  $('button.row-add').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $table = $(this).parents('table');
    var $top = $table.find('tr.line_items').first();
    var $new = $top.clone(true);

    $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $new.insertBefore($top);
    $new.find('input[type=text]').val('');
    autoCalcSetup();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jautocalc@1.3.1/dist/jautocalc.js"></script>

<div id="cart">
  <table name="cart">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Item Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_items">
      <td><button class="row-remove">Remove</button></td>
      <td>Stuff</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" value="9.99"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_items">
      <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
      <td>more item</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" value="12.50"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_items">
      <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
      <td>more item</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" value="99.99"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" value="" jAutoCalc="SUM({item_total})"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        Tax:
        <select name="tax" type='hidden'>
          <option value=".06">CT Tax</option>
          <option selected value=".00">Tax Free</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tax_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{sub_total} * {tax}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="grand_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{sub_total} + {tax_total}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="99"><button class="row-add">Add Row</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>



   //the form i want to integrate it on is below

 @extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jautocalc@1.3.1/dist/jautocalc.js"></script>
<div class="block bg-warning ">
  <h1 class="lead p-3 container">Expense Requests Form</h1></div>
  @include('inc.messages')
<div class="container">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    
    <form action='{{url('posts')}}' method='POST'>
        @csrf
        
    

    <div class="form-group"style="margin-top:20px;">
      <label for="exampleSelectRounded0">SUBJECT</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter ..."name="subject" value={{old('subject')}}>
    </div>
    
    <div> <label for="exampleSelectRounded0" style="margin-top:10px;">DRIVERS DETAILS</label><h6>Drivers Name</h6>
      
    <select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="senders_name" name="drivers_name">
       @foreach ($staffs as $staff )
      <option  value="{{ $staff->id }}" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $staff->senders_name }}</option>
      @endforeach
 
      
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <h6>Drivers Phone Number</h6>
    <select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="exampleSelectRounded0" name="drivers_phone_number">
  
       @foreach ($staffs as $staff )
      <option  value="{{ $staff->id }}" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $staff->senders_number }}</option>
      @endforeach
      
    
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelectRounded0" style="margin-top:25px;">VEHICLE DETAILS</label>

    <h6>Vehicle Name</h6>
    <select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="exampleSelectRounded0" name="vehicle_name">
      @foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle )
      <option  value="{{ $vehicle->id }}" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $vehicle->vehicle_name }}</option>
      @endforeach
     
    </select> 
  </div>

    <div><h6>Vehicle Number</h6>
    <select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="exampleSelectRounded0" name="vehicle_number">
     
      <option  value="" {{ old('---select your vehicle name---') == "---select your vehicle name---" ? 'selected' : '---select your vehicle name---' }}>---select your vehicle name---</option>
       
      @foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle )
      <option  value="{{ $vehicle->id }}" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $vehicle->vehicle_number }}</option>
      @endforeach
      
    </select> 
  </div>



  <div>
    <label for="exampleSelectRounded0" style="margin-top:25px;">REPAIR DESCRIPTION</label><h6>Repair Type</h6>
    <select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="exampleSelectRounded0" name="repair_type">
      <option  value="" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}></option>
      <option  value="Replacement" {{ old('repair_type') == "Replacement" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Replacement</option>
      <option  value="To Be Fixed" {{ old('repair_type') == "To Be Fixed" ? 'selected' : '' }}>To Be Fixed</option>
     </select>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group"style="margin-top:20px;">
      <h6>Repair Parts and Prices(₦)</h6>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter ..."name="repair_with_price" value={{old('repair_with_price')}}>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"style="margin-top:20px;">
      <h6>Total Repairs(₦)</h6>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" name="total_repair" value={{ old('total_repair') }}>
  </div>

  
  /* THE JQUERY DYNAMIC FORM START HERE*/

<div id="cart">
  <table name="cart">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Item Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_items">
      <td><button class="row-remove">Remove</button></td>
      <td>Stuff</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" value="9.99"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_items">
      <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
      <td>more item</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" value="12.50"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_items">
      <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
      <td>more item</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" value="99.99"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" value="" jAutoCalc="SUM({item_total})"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        Tax:
        <select name="tax" type='hidden'>
          <option value=".06">CT Tax</option>
          <option selected value=".00">Tax Free</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tax_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{sub_total} * {tax}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="grand_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{sub_total} + {tax_total}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="99"><button class="row-add">Add Row</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

  

  <div>
    <label for="exampleSelectRounded0" style="margin-top:15px;">REPAIR VENDOR DETAILS</label><h6>Vendor's Name</h6>
    <select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="exampleSelectRounded0" name="vendor_name">
      @foreach ($vendors as $vendor )

      <option  value="{{ $vendor->id }}" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $vendor->vendors_name }}</option>
      @endforeach
      
    
      </select>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;"><h6>Vendor's Phone Number</h6>
    <select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="exampleSelectRounded0" name="vendor_phone">

      @foreach ($vendors as $vendor )

      <option  value="{{ $vendor->id }}" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $vendor->vendors_phone_number }}</option>
      @endforeach
     {{-- <option  value="" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}></option>
        <option  value="vendor phone 1" {{ old('vendor_phone') == "vendor phone 1" ? 'selected' : '' }}>vendor phone 1</option>
        <option  value="vendor phone 2" {{ old('vendor_phone') == "vendor phone 2" ? 'selected' : '' }}>vendor phone 2</option>--}}
      </select> 
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="status_value" 
    id="inputID" value='1' >
    <input type="hidden" name="status_option" 
    id="inputID" value="Under Review" >







  <div class="form-group"style="margin-top:25px;">
    <label>NATURE OF FAULT</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter ..." name="nature_of_fault">{{old('nature_of_fault')}}</textarea>

  <div class="form-group"style="margin-top:25px;">
    <label>JUSTIFICATION</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter ..." name="justification" >{{old('justification')}}</textarea>
</div>
  
  
    
    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:100px;" rows="5" type="submit" placeholder="Enter ...">Enter</button>
  </div>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
$(function() {

  function autoCalcSetup() {
    $('div#cart').jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $('div#cart tr.line_items').jAutoCalc({
      keyEventsFire: true,
      decimalPlaces: 2,
      emptyAsZero: true
    });
    $('div#cart').jAutoCalc({
      decimalPlaces: 2
    });
  }
  autoCalcSetup();


  $('#cart tbody').on("click", "button.row-remove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    autoCalcSetup();

  });

  $('#cart tbody').on("click", 'button.row-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $table = $(this).closest('tbody');
    var $top = $table.find('tr.line_items').first();
    var $new = $top.clone(true);

    $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $new.insertBefore($top);
    $new.find('input[type=text]').val('');
    autoCalcSetup();

  });

});
      //-->
    </script>
</div>
</form>
@endsection
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. This does not sound like a Laravel issue at all

Comment: Please post a version where you use `extendlayout` whatever that is

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, yeah it works when you run it alone but doesnt when i place it in my laravel project. I mean once I extend it in my view. I dont know if there is a comflict somewhere i dont know about

Answer (score 0):

You are not delegating correctly

Here is an improved version with valid HTML

Also tables do not have name attributes

```js
$(function() {

  function autoCalcSetup() {
    $('div#cart').jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $('div#cart tr.line_items').jAutoCalc({
      keyEventsFire: true,
      decimalPlaces: 2,
      emptyAsZero: true
    });
    $('div#cart').jAutoCalc({
      decimalPlaces: 2
    });
  }
  autoCalcSetup();


  $('#cart tbody').on("click", "button.row-remove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    autoCalcSetup();

  });

  $('#cart tbody').on("click", 'button.row-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $table = $(this).closest('tbody');
    var $top = $table.find('tr.line_items').first();
    var $new = $top.clone(true);

    $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $new.insertBefore($top);
    $new.find('input[type=text]').val('');
    autoCalcSetup();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jautocalc@1.3.1/dist/jautocalc.js"></script>

<div id="cart">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Item Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="line_items">
        <td><button class="row-remove">Remove</button></td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price" value="9.99"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="line_items">
        <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
        <td>more item</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price" value="12.50"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="line_items">
        <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
        <td>more item</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price" value="99.99"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Subtotal</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" value="" jAutoCalc="SUM({item_total})"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          Tax:
          <select name="tax" type='hidden'>
            <option value=".06">CT Tax</option>
            <option selected value=".00">Tax Free</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tax_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{sub_total} * {tax}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="grand_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{sub_total} + {tax_total}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="99"><button class="row-add">Add Row</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am Sorry for the late reply, I was taking a look at your corrections. It still did not calculate when i place it inside my form, I think i will need to attach my target form so you understand what i am trying to do

Comment: Sure - the more relevant code the better. Just please do not post template. Post rendered HTML

Comment: I just added thead and tbody tags and removed the name="cart" from the table

Comment: I just updated the code, sorry i am not familiar with using stack overflow code snippet yet, I am sorry if you might need to rearrange it, also, by 'Post rendere HTML' did you mean html form accepting post request?

Comment: I can do nothing with code like `@foreach ($staffs as $staff )
      <option  value="{{ $staff->id }}" {{ old('') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $staff->senders_name }}</option>
      @endforeach`

Comment: Okay, I get what you mean now, thanks.

Comment: The thing is I dont need help with the code you highlighted or the post rendered html, they are working fine, what I am interested in is how i can integrate the jquery table in my form with laravel